# Catching an exception from wrapped EAP request to WCF

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, exception

I have a WCF request in WP8 environment that I wrapped according to this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#EAP

My call to the WCF service proceeds as follows:

```
try 
{
    var result = await mWCFClient.PerformRequestAsync();
} 
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

where PerformRequestAsync is an extension method. i.e.

```
public static ResultType PerformRequestAsync(this WCFClient client)
{
   // EAP wrapper code
}
```

What happens is that occasionally something goes wrong on the WCF service and it returns "NotFound". I am not 100% sure why this happens and it seems like a rare occasion. The problem, however, is not the WCF service behavior, but the fact that it breaks in the EndPerformRequestAsync() in the automatically generated WCF code instead of going to my exception handler.

How and where should I be catching this exception as it never reaches my intended handler?!

**[Edit]**

As per Stephen's request, I've included the wrapper code here:

```
public static Task<RegistrationResult> RegisterAsync(this StoreServiceReference.StoreServiceClient client, string token, bool dummy)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<RegistrationResult>();
    EventHandler<RegisterCompletedEventArgs> handler = null;
    handler = (_, e) =>
    {
        client.RegisterCompleted -= handler;
        if (e.Error != null)
            tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
        else if (e.Cancelled)
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        else
            tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
    };
    client.RegisterCompleted += handler;
    PerformStoreRequest(client, () => client.RegisterAsync(), token);
    return tcs.Task;
}

private static void PerformStoreRequest(StoreServiceClient client, Action action, string token)
{
    using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        requestMessage.Headers[STORE_TOKEN_HTTP_HEADER] = token;

        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;

        action.Invoke();
        // TODO: Do we need to add handler here?
    }
}
```

Now that I look at it, I think the problem stems from the nature of action invoke. But adding custom headers to WP8 WCF services already is a pain.
The action inside is an async operation, but Invoke as far as I know is not.
What's the proper way to go about it here?

Comment: Are you sure it never reaches your handler? Try unchecking the "Thrown" checkboxes in the Debug -> Exceptions dialog.

Comment: They're all unchecked. This is so peculiar. And it appears to be very rare occasion too, it's hard to test out properly.

Comment: I'm not even sure what the error is about though. It's a System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException. "The remote server returned and error: NotFound." and it has a corresponding WebException in innerexception.

Comment: Post your EAP wrapper code. It's possible that it's not placing the exception on the returned task in all cases.

Comment: I posted it. I now think the problem is not with the wrapper code itself, but the PerformStoreRequest. That being said, I'm still rather clueless on how to make this comprehensible. I feel like I've probably overcomplicated things.